# HttpException on OutputStream. How to correctly send file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, httpresponse

I use code below to send file from ASP.NET Rest Api to client. Sometimes I see error logs "The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800703E3." Is this correct method to send stream response?

```
var outputFileName;                   
context.Response.ContentType = WebHelper.GetMimeType(outputFileName);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("{0}; filename={1}", "attachment", outputFileName));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", binaryData.Length.ToString());
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data in a file, it is much better to use [Response.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx) than Response.OutputStream.Write since TransmitFile will not buffer the file data in memory.

As for the error message that you are receiving, this is perfectly normal. If the user disconnects from the network, cancels the download, or shuts down their browser while the file is being transmitted, this error message will be raised to let you know that the transfer was not completed.

Comment: Response.TransmitFile do not support In Memory file transfer and in my situation I do not have file on disc, it is in memory.

Comment: @Tomas: Ok, I didn't see from your code whether you had previously loaded the data from file or not, so I thought it was worth mentioning. However, the information about the error message applies to your situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
context.Response.Clear();

context.Response.ContentType = ...;
context.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", ... );
// do not set Content-Length
context.Response.Write( binaryData );
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: Could you explain your code? Why content-length is not set? I think it is not good idea to hide response length while sending file to user.

Comment: If the content-length is missing, it should be added automatically by the engine. This way there should be no inconsistency between the content length declared in the header and the actual content length. I think that this inconsistency is the reason you get the exception.